# trying to retreive txt messages from old disconnected iphone 4s

Tags: iphone

i have a iphone 4s which is not currently connected but i am wanting to get old text messages from in but for some reason the conversation only goes back so far and does not contain the entire conversation which could have partly included imessages as well

Comment: First part is easy, make a backup from your iPhone 4s with iTunes. The second part is harder.. how do you merge 2 message databases...

Comment: Not sure what you mean - could you please explain what you want to say by 'not currently connected?'

Do you have access to the phone? Can you unlock it?

Comment: Yes i have accesss. It is not locked. It is not connected to a service provider

Answer (score 1):

You might have already tried all basic troubleshooting, but if not, it’s worth trying

- a [force restart](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201559) or/and
- iPhone Reset: Tap Settings > General > Reset > Reset All Settings
- logging out and back in to your iCloud account

Let me know if any of these worked.